# Passing datastore value as parameter OnRowCommand asp:ButtonField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Was wondering if any of you can help me or point me in the right direction

I am using a asp:GridView to display some data, and I added a ButtonField as one of the columns, what I want to do is pass the value of one of the text columns to the OnRowCommand function and do some calculations with it.

My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSchedule" runat="server" OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" OnRowCommand="RowButtonClicked" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="11px"
            CssClass="Grid" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Schedule Name" SortExpression="Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message Text" SortExpression="Message">
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="10px" />
         </asp:BoundField>
         <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ViewDetails" Text="View" ControlStyle-CssClass="ActionButton" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The value I want to pass is not listed above, but it is in the store, I am not displaying that column.

This is the function that I am calling from the grid

```
protected void RowButtonClicked(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So what I want to know is, how can I pass the value of one of the columns, even if I have to add that column to the grid and just set it's visibility to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `DataKeyNames` and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the GridView to get to the values you need.  The Data Key Names would map to the column names of the data in your data source.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSchedule" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID,Date,Name" OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="11px" CssClass="Grid" 
        AllowSorting="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridViewSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Schedule Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message Text" SortExpression="Message">
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="10px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ViewDetails" Text="View" ControlStyle-CssClass="ActionButton" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And then access the value like this:

```
 protected void GridViewSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSchedule.DataKeys[GridViewSchedule.SelectedIndex].Values["ID"]);
 }
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was still using the `OnRowCommand="RowButtonClicked"` and then using `int val = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSchedule.DataKeys[GridViewSchedule.SelectedIndex].Values["ID"]);` provided by you. Thanks lead me in the right direction